# comparing text containing &nbsp;

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to make sure that the label of the following element is indeed "Select Date" without using regex:

```
<strong id="id1">Select &nbsp;Date</strong>
```

But both of the following codes  do not compare to this label:

```
$("#id1").text().trim() === "Select Date"

$("#id1").text().trim() === "Select  Date" //extra space there
```

**How should I detect this label?**

Comment: Open the developer tools and type `$("#id1").text().trim()` into the `console`; what's the value?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski ... yes that worked

Comment: Does any of the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore the spaces you could do:

```
function compareStrings(a, b){
    return a.split(/\s/).join('') == b.split(/\s/).join('');
}

console.log(compareStrings($("#id1").text(), "Select Date")); // true
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n8q52w9x/

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do:

```
$("#id1").html().replace(/&nbsp;/g, '') === "Select Date";
```